# Unable to upload file on server using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

This code works fine,no any error but does not insert file in database and destination folder after hit upload button.

**HTML Form**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="includes/parts-cat/zip-download.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <label for="">Upload File:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="file" name="myfile">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label></label>
                <input id="dngr" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="save" style="margin-top:15px;" value="Upload">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php
include_once('../dbconfig.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fileupload";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$files = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// Uploads files
if (isset($_POST['save'])) { // if save button on the form is clicked
    // name of the uploaded file
    $filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $destination = 'projectdocument/' . $filename;
    $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    if (!in_array($extension, ['zip', 'pdf', 'docx', 'xlsx'])) {
        echo "You file extension must be .zip, .pdf or .docx";
    } elseif ($_FILES['myfile']['size'] > 10000000000) {
        echo "File too large!";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination)) {
            $mysql = "INSERT INTO fileupload (name,size, downloads) VALUES ('$filename', $size, 0)";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $mysql)) {
                echo "File uploaded successfully";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Failed to upload file.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have searched all over and still unable to figure out why unable to upload files.
Please give me suggestion if any mistake or error in above code.

Comment: Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `__DIR__`

just change

`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'//projectdocument/'. $_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) {`